# Efficiently read from REST endpoint and compress result in Python

Tags: python, gzip

I have a data export job that reads data from a REST endpoint and then saves the data in a temporary compressed file before being written to S3. This was working for smaller payloads:

```
import gzip
import urllib2

# Fails when writing too much data at once    
def get_data(url, params, fileobj):
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
    event_data = request.read()
    with gzip.open(fileobj.name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(event_data)
```

However, as the data size increased I got an error that seems to indicate I'm writing too much data at once:

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gzip.py", line 241, in write
    self.fileobj.write(self.compress.compress(data))
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int`

I tried modifying the code to read from the REST endpoint line-by-line and write each line to the file, but this was incredibly slow, probably because the endpoint isn't setup to handle that.

```
# Incredibly slow
def get_data(url, params, fileobj):
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
    with gzip.open(fileobj.name, 'wb') as f:
        for line in request:
            f.write(line)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, such as by reading the entire payload at once, like in the first example, but then efficiently reading line-by-line from the data now residing in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is what StringIO is for. By turning my payload into a StringIO object I was able to read from it line-by-line and write to a gzipped file without any errors.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

def get_data(url, params, fileobj):
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
    event_data = StringIO(request.read())
    with gzip.open(fileobj.name, 'wb') as f:
        for line in event_data:
            f.write(line)
```